# Icons modified from 4.1.0 to 4.2.0

Tags: font-awesome

I just found out that there is some icons which have been modified such as the fa fa-user or fa fa-university, if you switch between 4.1.0 and 4.2.0 you'll see that it's not the same..
Is there a way to keep the old Awesome Icons version but add 'manually' the new icons ?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.

The ways to customize Font-Awasome icons are listed in [issue 3168](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/3168).

> In the fonts folder, you will find the `.otf` file used to develop the font.
>   I suppose you need to edit that one with illustrator and export with http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator.

Note:

- the [`fa-university` in 4.2](http://fontawesome.io/icon/university/) is quite similar to the [university ("`icon-bank`") of 4.1](http://fontello.com/#search=university)
- same between [`fa-user` in 4.2](http://fontawesome.io/icon/user/) and [user in 4.1](http://fontello.com/#search=user).